# The relationship between $f_{i}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, combinations, symmetric-polynomials, elementary-functions

Let $\lambda_{i}$ be a real number for any $1 \le i \le n$, defining $f_{i}$ as following $$f_{i} = \sum^{n}_{j=1} (\lambda_{j})^{i}$$
Suppose we know $f_{1},f_{2},f_{3}$ and $f_{4}$, then can we express $f_{5}$ and $f_{6}$ by $f_{1},f_{2},f_{3}$ and $f_{4}$? If yes, what the formulas in detail? Is there any references and books about it? I would be truly grateful for anyone who tells me anything about this question.

Comment: $f_n=f_{n-1}+\lambda_n^n$. If $\lambda_n$ is arbitrary you can't predict its value.

Comment: we  can not get  this equation, for example $f_{1} = \sum^{n}_{j=1} \lambda_{j}, f_{2} = \sum^{n}_{j=1} \lambda^{2}_{j}$, but the equation you write can not hold.

Comment: Are the $\lambda_j$ given or unknown?

Comment: I believe it has no differences? May we can think it is given.

Answer (score 1):

Let the $\lambda_j$ be the roots of the polynomial $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\lambda^{n-k}$, with $a_0 = 1$. By [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), the $a_k$ are elementary symmetric polynomials in the $\lambda_j$ times $(-1)^k$. Then by [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities), we have for $i \le n$
$$
f_i = -i a_i-\sum_{k = 1}^{i-1}a_k f_{i-k}
$$
and for $i > n$,
$$
f_i = -\sum_{k = 1}^na_{k}f_{i-k}.
$$
Thus, if we know $f_1$, $f_2$, ..., $f_n$, we can reverse the first identity to get $a_k = -\sum_{i =1}^kf_i a_{k-i}/k$, and thus recursively find the $a_k$ in terms of the $f_i$. Then we can use the second identity recursively to find any $f_i$ for $i > n$ in terms of $f_1$, $f_2$, ..., $f_n$. Note that we need all $n$ values of $f$, as otherwise we can't pin down every value of $a_k$.

I'm not aware of any explicit formula for the $f_i$, but you'll find they are linear combinations of terms of the form $\prod_{j=1}^nf_j^{p_i}$, where $\sum jp_j = i$.